# NullPointerException on setOnItemClickListener in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, onitemclicklistener

I get a NullPointerException on the setOnItemClickListener in this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    c = getApplicationContext();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSchedules);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    File schedules = new File(c.getFilesDir().toString() + "/testthreepdf");
    schedulesList = schedules.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() 
    {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) 
        {
            return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
        }
    });

    if(schedulesList.length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < schedulesList.length; i++) 
        {
            pdflist.add(schedulesList[i].getName().toString());
        }
        adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {
    String path = schedulesList[(int) id].getAbsolutePath();

    try {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondMainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

I've used this in several activities and it always works, but it won't work here and I can't seem to find the problem?

Comment: can you post the error log just so I can see what's going on?

Comment: You should add the stack trace from the NPE to your question.

Comment: *this* cant be null so only *lv* remains

Comment: `//setContentView(R.layout.main);` This line is necessary. Why is it commented out?

Comment: @matiash That was the problem, it works now

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively straight forward problem so I don't know whether this is really worth answer but.. uncomment the

```
//setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

to

```
setContentView
```